# CSS/JavaScript - Mobile JavaScript stops working under 771px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have very strange problem.

I am developing mobile version to my website and i have very strange problem.

When i open my page with mobile that is having screen height over 770px everything is working well. So when i open it with **771px** it's works.

But if i change the screen height to 770px the javascripts is not working any more.

First of all i found all `@media only screen and (min-width: 771px) {` rules in my CSS files and replaced them to `@media only screen and (min-width: 350px) {` but even with that change it is not working.

I've searched for any occurence of `770` or `771` in all my CSS files and style rules and there is none like that, but still the javascript is not working.

Here is my complete javascript: http://pastebin.com/HJyDrVYd

Here is my complete css: http://pastebin.com/M3Cu5qfF

Here is my HTML output of the page on which i have this problem: http://pastebin.com/CBgedJmZ

I run out of suggestions from where the problem may come and why the mobile version have working js with screen height 771px or higher but not lower.

Can you give any suggestion and help ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with jsut the problem code, not your entire site dump

Comment: You have a syntax error in your JavaScript. Check your browser console.